# SwiftUI Bar View display bool value

Tags: swift, swiftui, charts, bar-chart

I want to customize a Bar View like this with SwiftUI.  it will display the bool value retrieved from the API, the width of a value depends on the timestamp value from the API.  Besides, when clicking on a value, the bool value and timestamp will be retrieved to display on the View.

[image]

I tried to find a way to customize with BarChartView from danielgindi's DGCharts library but it didn't seem very good.
Can someone with experience handling similar cases help me with ideas?

Comment: SwiftUI now has its own Charts API, I would start there. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/charts

Comment: @koen Yes I know it.  but it is only available on ios 16, my application is at least 14

Comment: Please [edit] your question with all relevant information. Including a [example] showing what you have tried and what’s not working. See also [ask].